# Finding the size and relative position of a chart's components w.r.t. chart's bounds

Tags: java, javafx

I'm writing a code using JavaFX, where there are multiple charts (e.g. `LineChart`s or `ScatterChart`s) on an `AnchorPane`, each of which at a different position. The user must be able to modify chart data, mouse dragging the plot area w.r.t. the chart, change tick labels and lengths, define labels for the axes, title or legends, and change the color of any of the chart components. At each action, the relative position of any of the chart components (e.g. plot area, axes, legends, labels, title or tick marks) w.r.t. the chart bounds is needed for further processing. Visually speaking, I wish to find the position and size of the red and green rectangles in the following given chart:

[image]

The following two code snippets do not give accurate results:

**Code 1**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public class Test8 extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        AnchorPane anchorPane=new AnchorPane();

        Scene scene=new Scene(anchorPane,600,400);

        stage.setScene(scene);

        stage.show();

        LineChart<Number,Number> lineChart=new LineChart<>(new NumberAxis(),new NumberAxis());

        Region region= (Region) lineChart.lookup(".chart-plot-background");

        anchorPane.getChildren().add(lineChart);

        System.out.println(region.getBoundsInParent());

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }


}
```

output: `BoundingBox [minX:0.0, minY:0.0, minZ:0.0, width:0.0, height:0.0, depth:0.0, maxX:0.0, maxY:0.0, maxZ:0.0]`

**Code 2**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public class Test8 extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        AnchorPane anchorPane=new AnchorPane();

        Scene scene=new Scene(anchorPane,600,400);

        stage.setScene(scene);

        LineChart<Number,Number> lineChart=new LineChart<>(new NumberAxis(),new NumberAxis());

        Region region= (Region) lineChart.lookup(".chart-plot-background");

        anchorPane.getChildren().add(lineChart);

        stage.show();

        System.out.println(region.getBoundsInParent());

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }


}
```

output: `BoundingBox [minX:38.0, minY:10.0, minZ:0.0, width:443.0, height:346.0, depth:0.0, maxX:481.0, maxY:356.0, maxZ:0.0]`

The only difference between the two snippets is the position of `stage.show()` command.

**Question**

What is the *correct* way of finding relative size and position of chart components w.r.t. chart bounds when the chart resides on an `AnchorPane`? Are the two code snippets above modifiable or do I need a different approach?

Comment: *"At each action, the relative position of any of the chart components ... is needed"*. If the layout geometry is only needed on user action, then can't you just compute them when the user performs the action? This would necessarily be after layout has been performed, so would be equivalent to your second code example, which gives the correct results. (It's still not clear why you really need any of this anyway; if you change any of the properties you listed then the chart should just update and take care of its own layout.)

Comment: I'm writing an application, in which a user can choose to add a new line chart from its menu and drop it on the main canvas. The user must be able to customize the chart, as mentioned in the question. Finally, the set of user-defined charts should be exported to a pdf or tex file (this is where I need processing on chart components).